# Как сделать поиск на главной странице в Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Есть SPA. Перевожу его на Next.js.  Главная страница выводит список статей и пререндерится через  SSR.
После того как страница уже загружена на клиент , нужно организовать поиск и  выводить данные по результату его поиска. И тут у меня проблема.  Раньше оно работало так

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(search);
    const text = query.get('seacrhText');

    let queryParams: {
        pageNum: number;
        pageSize: number;
        search?: string;
    } = {
        pageNum,
        pageSize: ARTICLES_PER_PAGE,
    };

    if (text) {
        queryParams = { search: text, ...queryParams };
    }

    dispatch(searchArticle(queryParams));
}, [search, userIsAuth, pageNum]);
```

Но теперь получаю ошибку что этот код не может обрабатываться на пререндере (useEffect).
Вопрос как  организовать  поиск так что  бы он работал и на серверной стороне и на клиенте? Если вы знаете примеры, или можете подсказать куда смотреть, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какая версия? 13я? Какой роутер? Новый App Router или старый Pages router? И самое главное - раз вы спрашиваете по поводу ошибки, но нужно текст ошибки прикреплять.
Предполагаю, что вы просто скопировали код из SPA в Next.js с сохранением структуры.

Предполагаю, что вы получили ошибку  `useEffect only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-client-hook-in-server-component`, где вам прямым текстом говорят в чем проблема и где искать.

Если это так, значит вы совсем не понимаете новых фишек продвинутого рендеринга в App Router в Next.js 13, в этом случае рекомендую работать на старом Pages Router.

По поводу ошибки с "use client" - Next.js просит вас указать что это клиентский компонент, потому что по умолчанию Next.js 13 в App router рендерит страницу ТОЛЬКО на сервере. с "use client" вы указываете, что некоторая часть действий происходит также на клиенте.
Просто укажите эту директиву сверху файла.

Вообще, по поводу различия клиентских и серверных компонентов есть целые обсуждения.  Я на английском форуме написал об этом более подробно: [Вот мой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077564/9047572)

Документация:

1. [Серверные компоненты](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components)
2. [Когда и что использовать](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns)

Если у вас задача - просто "как-нибудь" перенести проект на next.js, то я советую взять версию Next.js 12 или хотя бы использовать легаси Pages router. Он более похож на роутер, используемый в SPA реакта.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Одно что  я 13  некстом я пользуюсь впервые. да роутинг через App.  Но у меня никак не вкладывается в голове  как сделать так что  бы один и тот же компонент делал запрос на серверной стороне и на клиентской.

Comment: ну смотри - комопзиция 


// This pattern works:
// You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a
import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  )
}


как мне передать в сервеный компонент что  я нажал на кнопку и ему нужно обновится? или мне нужно передать параметр который будет влиять на  запрос  который происходит на серверной части?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко блин, ну невозможно же читать неотформатированный код. Тем более я уже скинул все нужные ссылки. Невозможно освоить фреймворк за час. Найдите какой-нибудь Starter проект и освойте его. Тем более "как передать параметр" - ну блин, тема "как отправить http запрос на бэкенд" в тему вопроса не входила.

В useEffect можно послать запрос через fetch например, но ведь на бэкенде должен быть обработчик этого (route.js, https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)